# Replace partial string in Pandas Dataframe with dictionary value

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame (df) where some of the words contain encoding replacement characters. I want to replace these words with replacement words from a dictionary (translations).

```
translations = {'gr�nn': 'gronn', 'm�nst': 'menst'}
df = pd.DataFrame(["gr�nn Y", "One gr�nn", "Y m�nst/line X"])

df.replace(translations, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

However, it doesn't seem to capture all the instances.
Current output:

```
                0
0         gronn Y
1       One gr�nn
2  Y m�nst/line X
```

Do I need to specify any regex patterns to enable the replacement to also capture partial words within a string?

Expected output:

```
                0
0         gronn Y
1       One gronn
2  Y menst/line X
```

Comment: if you have just gronn, i suggest you to replace all gr.nn by gronn

Comment: @Frenchy This is just a sample set - there full set contains multiple variations.

Comment: if you have some replaced and other not replaced, that mean is different character

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn your translations into regex find/replace strings:

```
translations = {r'(.*)gr�nn(.*)': r'\1gronn\2', r'(.*)m�nst(.*)': r'\1menst\2'}
df = pd.DataFrame(["gr�nn Y", "One gr�nn", "Y m�nst/line X"])
df.replace(translations, regex=True)
```

Returns:

```
    0
0   gronn Y
1   One gronn
2   Y menst/line X
```

Comment: Very Nice idea. :) +1

Comment: you are supposing � is same.So � could hide different values (hex) behind its visual

Comment: @Frenchy I guess in that case you could use another group `r'(.*)gr(.*)nn(.*)': r'\1gronn\3'`